# Can't generate multiple enemies in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to add multiple enemies to my game, but even though I have put the code to do so in, no more than one enemy is showing. I have tried to debug to find any errors, but I can't find any.

```
import random
import math
import pygame

# initialise pygame
pygame.init()

# player 1
playerimage = pygame.image.load("Main Player.png")
playerX = 365
playerY = 700
playerX_change = 0

# laser
# ready - bullet not on screen
# fire - bullet is shown on screen and is moving
laserimage = pygame.image.load("laser.png")
laserX = 0
laserY = 700
laserY_change = 10
laser_currentstate = "ready"

# alien player / random movement = random.randint()
alienimage = []
alienX = []
alienY = []
alienX_change = []
alienY_change = []
amount_aliens = 3
```

I've attempted to make multiple aliens, but the code doesn't work either.

```
for i in range(amount_aliens):
    alienimage.append(pygame.image.load('alien.png'))
    alienX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    alienY.append(random.randint(50, 200))
    alienX_change.append(4)
    alienY_change.append(7)

score = 0


# define player
def main_player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimage, (x, y))


# define laster
def fire_laser(x, y):
    global laser_currentstate
    laser_currentstate = "fire"
    screen.blit(laserimage, (x + 16, y + 10))


# define alien
def alien(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(alienimage[i], (x, y))


# collision detection
def hascollision(alienX, alienY, laserX, laserY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(alienX - laserX, 2)) + (math.pow(alienY - laserY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# background
background = pygame.image.load('stars.png')

# display and screen title/icon
(width, height) = (800, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
flip = pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.set_caption("space fighters")
pygame.event.get()
icon = pygame.image.load('logo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

from sys import exit

# loop of functions
executed = True
while executed:
    screen.fill((63, 62, 63))
    # image background
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # if key pressed, check which input, right or left?
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("key pressed")
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerX_change = -6
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerX_change = 6
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerX_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if laser_currentstate is "ready":
                    laserX = playerX
                fire_laser(laserX, laserY)

    # bounrary algorithm, prevents player moving out/enemy.
    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    # boundry algorithm, make sure alien doesn't go out of bountry
    for i in range(amount_aliens):
        alienX[i] += alienX_change[i]
        if alienX[i] <= 0:
            alienX_change[i] = 4
            alienY[i] += alienY_change[i]
        elif alienX[i] >= 736:
            alienX_change[i] = -4
            alienY[i] += alienY_change[i]

    # collision
    collision = hascollision(alienX[i], alienY[i], laserX, laserY)
    if collision:
        laserY = 650
        laser_currentstate = "ready"
        score += 5
        print(score)
        alienX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
        alienY[i] = random.randint(50, 200)

    alien(alienX[i], alienY[i], i)

    # movement of laser shot
    if laserY <= 0:
        laserY = 650
        laser_currentstate = "ready"

    if laser_currentstate is "fire":
        fire_laser(laserX, laserY)
        laserY -= laserY_change

    # updates screen to show screen
    main_player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I also can't get the game to quit by pressing the button.

Comment: There is thing called OOP. Have a look to ``class`` keyword. You can make your code better with it. For sure it is not about your problem.

Comment: Dont use parallel lists, this is a design antipattern. Use a list of dicts instead (where each dict holds the image, x, y, etc values for one given alien). It will also make it easier to move from plain dicts to real 'alien' objects when you'll start learning OO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

The collision detection and `alien(alienX[i], alienY[i], i)` have to be done in the for loop, which iterates all the aliens:

```py
executed = True
while executed:
    # [...]

    # boundry algorithm, make sure alien doesn't go out of bountry
    for i in range(amount_aliens):
        alienX[i] += alienX_change[i]
        if alienX[i] <= 0:
            alienX_change[i] = 4
            alienY[i] += alienY_change[i]
        elif alienX[i] >= 736:
            alienX_change[i] = -4
            alienY[i] += alienY_change[i]

        # INDENTATION !!!

        # collision
        collision = hascollision(alienX[i], alienY[i], laserX, laserY)
        if collision:
            laserY = 650
            laser_currentstate = "ready"
            score += 5
            print(score)
            alienX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
            alienY[i] = random.randint(50, 200)

        alien(alienX[i], alienY[i], i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a feeling it would be something small which i would miss.

Answer (score 2):

The problemis that you only call

```
 alien(alienX[i], alienY[i], i)
```

Once, where you should call it once for every one of your aliens (so in your `for` loop)

Comment: This. The whole laser-alien collision and this line should be indented to be in the `for` loop.